# Failed to run bazel with error "@local_config_cc//:armabi_cc_toolchain_config.bzl: no such file"

Tags: linux, macos, build, bazel

I'm totally new to Bazel and I'm trying to ru `bazel run //:gazelle` on a project I'm currently in the development team for. This command runs smoothly in my `20.04.1 Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux' machine but it failes with the following error an m1 mac:

```bash
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_<USERNAME>/<random-hash>/external/bazel_tools/src/tools/launcher/BUILD:9:14: Target '@bazel_tools//src/tools/launcher:launcher' depends on toolchain '@local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-darwin_x86_64', which cannot be found: error loading package '@local_config_cc/': cannot load '@local_config_cc//:armabi_cc_toolchain_config.bzl': no such file'
```

I checked out these links, but since I'm not very experienced I found it hard to figure out what to do exactly in order to fix this issue:

- https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/issues/1198
- https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/issues/2089#issuecomment-540829622
- [bazel rules_foreign_cc - //:<target> depends on @local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-k8 in repository @local_config_cc which failed to fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71243287/bazel-rules-foreign-cc-target-depends-on-local-config-cc-cc-compiler-k)

The code base I'm trying to run bazel on and then eventually build (with `bazel build //...`) consists of Golang and Python codes, if that helps.
Sorry if this question is so simple, I've just spent a good amount of time finding an answer, yet no success. Hope you guys would help me out on this.

Comment: Can you build a simple Hello World Go demo? E.g. this https://github.com/Vertexwahn/BazelDemos/tree/main/hello_world/Go?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/issues/2221#issuecomment-532793595)